# Incron-Job started Script but only the first command

Tags: bash, cron, cancellation, incron

My goal is to get a/all list/s out of the mycroft skill "List-Manager" in formated and splitted txt-files to transfer them to my Nextcloud-Notes-Skill. Sure, Hey Google and Alexa are the easiest options but I don't like them.
The bash-script I wrote does this work (formatting and splitting) in the terminal.

This is the textfile the mycroft skill uses...
*{"Remind me": ["remind_item_1", "remind_item_2"], "shopping": ["mate", "book", "keyboard", "bavarian beer"]}*

and I get these two textfiles
Name of the first textfile: Remind me

- [ ] remind_item_1
- [ ] remind_item_2

Name of the second textfile: shopping

- [ ] mate
- [ ] book
- [ ] keyboard
- [ ] bavarian beer

Before we go to the code below here somme infos. First, I suspect there is a much better way to get to the same result. I'm a selfmade "something like a programmer" and certainly not a pro and I don't want to offend anyone when I call myself a programmer. Second, I want to do it with
on-board resources. Third, I like to learn new things and I never have done bash-scripting.

The monitoring of the file which changed does "incron". Every time I change the list incron starts a script:

```
/opt/mycroft/skills/list-manager.lb803/data.json        IN_MODIFY       /bin/bash /home/pi/my_directory/notes_skill.sh
```

Incron works, it starts the script below **but only the first command (copy-command)**. I have every time the file "data_list_manager.txt" in my directory, but nothing further. Incron is allowed to act like user "pi" and "root". All the files have pi- or root-rights.
It stops after the "cp"-command. And I don't why.
In this version of code the result are only two list. In the moment it is okay, and I change it if I have a solution for ma question.
The directory reference `/bin/...` before the commands "echo" "sed" is, because I have read that the "incron" works different like the Terminal and needs the directory-name of the commands.
Thank you very much for your support!

```
#!/bin/bashcp 
cp /opt/mycroft/skills/list-manager.lb803/data.json /home/pi/my_directory/data_list_manager.txt
#wait
foo="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/data_list_manager.txt | /bin/sed s/[[{}\"]//g)"
foo="$(/bin/echo "$foo" | /bin/sed -e s/,[[:space:]]/@@/g -e s/:[[:space:]]/@@@@/g -e s/[]]/@@@@/g)"
foo="$(/bin/echo "$foo" | /bin/sed -e s/@@@@@@/\\n/g -e s/@@@@/\\n@@@/g)"
/bin/echo "$foo" >/home/pi/my_directory/splitfile.txt
/usr/bin/split -l2 /home/pi/my_directory/splitfile.txt
#wait
nam="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xaa | /bin/sed q)"
foo="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xaa | /bin/sed '2!d')"
foo="$(/bin/echo "$foo" | /bin/sed -e s/@@@/\-\ [\ ]\ /g -e s/@@/\\n\-\ [\ ]\ /g)"
/bin/echo "$foo" >/home/pi/my_directory/Listen/"$nam".txt
nam="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xab | /bin/sed q)"
foo="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xab | /bin/sed '2!d')"
foo="$(/bin/echo "$foo" | sed -e s/@@@/\-\ [\ ]\ /g -e s/@@/\\n\-\ [\ ]\ /g)"
/bin/echo "$foo" >/home/pi/my_directory/Listen/"$nam".txt
nam="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xac | /bin/sed q)"
foo="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xac | /bin/sed '2!d')"
foo="$(/bin/echo "$foo" | /bin/sed -e s/@@@/\-\ [\ ]\ /g -e s/@@/\\n\-\ [\ ]\ /g)"
/bin/echo "$foo" >/home/pi/my_directory/Listen/"$nam".txt
nam="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xad | /bin/sed q)"
foo="$(/bin/cat /home/pi/my_directory/xad | /bin/sed '2!d')"
foo="$(/bin/echo "$foo" | /bin/sed -e s/@@@/\-\ [\ ]\ /g -e s/@@/\\n\-\ [\ ]\ /g)"
/bin/echo "$foo" >/home/pi/my_directory/Listen/"$nam".txt
```

Comment: How do you know that _It stops after the "cp"-command_?

Comment: The cp command works because the file is copied. I tried it several times --> delete the file, start the process and it copied the file but nothing further happens.

Comment: To truly see what goes on in the script, you can add the line `set -x; exec 2>/tmp/logfile` at its start and look into the logfile afterwards.